# Customize colors in error plots with Plotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colors, bar-chart

I would like to change the colors in this error plot done with Plotlib in order to customize the choice. I would have the errors plots at label 0 (data1 and data3) with a different color (let's say green) with respect to the ones on the right (label 1, so data 2 and data4 and let's say red). Moreover, I would like to differentiate the two series (blue and orange with different shades of the colors). I tried different methods but did not manage to customize the plot.

[image: Final result]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create sample data
N = 2
data_1 = {
    'x': list(range(N)),
    'y': [2,3],
    'yerr': [0.2,0.2]}
data_2 = {
    'x': list(range(N)),
    'y': [4,5],
    'yerr': [0.4,0.2]}

data_3 = {
    'x': list(range(N)),
    'y': [6,10],
    'yerr': [0.3,0.7]}
data_4 = {
    'x': list(range(N)),
    'y': [8.1,10.6],
    'yerr': [0.1,0.8]}

# plot

# only errorbar
plt.subplot(121)
for data in [data_1, data_2]:
    plt.errorbar(**data, fmt='o')
plt.xlim([-1, 2])
plt.xticks([0, 1])

    
plt.subplot(122)
for data in [data_3, data_4]:
    plt.errorbar(**data, fmt='o')
plt.xlim([-1, 2])
plt.xticks([0, 1])
```

Comment: Provide a color to the plotting command like this: `plt.errorbar(**data, fmt='o', c='red')`. If you want slightly different shades, you'll have to provide them manually with hex codes. See https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colors.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, but how could you change the color inside the same dataframe (i.e., change the automatically assigned orange and blue colours)?

Comment: Ok, now I understood what you meant. See my answer if it satisfies your request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When plotting with `plot` or `errorbar`, a sequence of points all get the same color. You can specify it with `c=<some color>`. In your case, you want this sequence of points to have different colors. This can be done in two ways: 1) Iterate through the sequence of points and select a color or 2) use `plt.scatter` and provide a sequence of points. The latter method, however, doesn't have the `yerr` option. One solution is to plot twice, one for the error bars, another for the markers. See this example, using the same data you provided:

```py
plt.subplot(121)
for data in [data_1, data_2]:
    plt.errorbar(**data, linestyle="None", c='k') # Only errorbars
    plt.scatter(data['x'], data['y'], c=['green', 'red']) # Only markers
plt.xlim([-1, 2])
plt.xticks([0, 1])

plt.subplot(122)
for data in [data_3, data_4]:
    plt.errorbar(**data, linestyle="None", c='k')
    plt.scatter(data['x'], data['y'], c=['lime', 'lightcoral'])
plt.xlim([-1, 2])
plt.xticks([0, 1])
```

Yields this plot:

[image]

Now it's a matter of choosing the colors you want.

---

Answering the comment: To get the colors to vary, you'll need to supply them directly or find a way of mapping some unique information (say, a field "name" of a row in a dataframe). Here's two methods of supplying them directly:

```py
plt.errorbar(**data_1, linestyle="None", c='k')
plt.scatter(data_1['x'], data_1['y'], c=['green', 'red'])
plt.errorbar(**data_2, linestyle="None", c='k')
plt.scatter(data_2['x'], data_2['y'], c=['blue', 'purple'])

plt.xlim([-1, 2])
plt.xticks([0, 1])

plt.subplot(122)
for (data, colors) in [(data_3, ['lime', 'lightcoral']), (data_4, ['cornflowerblue', 'magenta' ])]:
    plt.errorbar(**data, linestyle="None", c='k')
    plt.scatter(data['x'], data['y'], c=colors)
plt.xlim([-1, 2])
plt.xticks([0, 1])
```

and the resulting graph:

[image]

Comment: It would be perfect if I could change the color even between the same series of values. For example, for the x=0 in plot #1 having different colors for the two points.

Comment: Then you'll have to find a way of assigning colors to each value, and that'll depend of what info you have. Hardcoding them might be simpler, but less flexible in the long run. It entirely depends on how reusable this code will be, and how much time you want to spend fiddling with the plot.